# Creating test records with FactoryGirl fails after using a concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have strange problem. I have models like this:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and a Addressable concern:

```
module Addressable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
    delegate :to_formatted_s, to: :address, prefix: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
  end
end
```

When I moved this code to concern my tests are failing:

```
Failure/Error: let(:patient) { create(:patient, :male, fullname: "Patient", pesel: "12345678901") }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `address=' for #<Patient:0x0000000550bb58>
```

My factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :patient do
    sequence(:fullname) { |n| "Patient #{n}" }
    pesel "12345678901"
    birth_date "2014-12-16"
    address

    trait :male do
      sex "male"
    end

    trait :female do
      sex "female"
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    sequence(:street) { |n| "Street #{n}" }
    sequence(:city) { |n| "City #{n}" }
    sequence(:zip_code) { |n| " 12-41#{n}" }
  end
end
```

Before I move this code into concern everything works as expected. Why now is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a naming conflict. I change concern name to AddresableConcern and now eveyrthing works as expected.